# Page won't display after clicking alert box

Tags: function, button, alert, innerhtml

Creating a game where the user answers 5 questions.  I want to display their score on a separate page when then complete the game.

This is how my page is set up:

```
<div data-role="page" id="displayScore">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>How Did You Go?</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p id="displayScore" align="center"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Play Again?" onClick="startGame();"/>
    <input type="button" value="Main Menu" onClick="" />
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
  <h4>AL</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my function:

```
function score()
{
    ans += "You scored <strong> " + score + " </strong> out of <strong> " + count + "!</strong>";
    document.getElementById('displayScore').innerHTML = displayScore;
}
```

Comment: how do i display a page displaying their score? Is the function correct?

Comment: where is the onlclick which triggers function score()?

Comment: can you take a look at my jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/losonic/5w9qc/8/

Comment: it is an alert box that is in another function

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass value to another page then you have to do one of the method between the following methods

1. pass the value by query string (using get method)
2. pass the value by post method
3. use cookies, localStorage or sessionStorage to store the value and retrieve the value in the another page.

if you want to open up a new window the the code will be like this

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','GoogleWindow', 800, 600);
```

if you want to create a new window with dynamic value then

```
<html>
    <body>

    <script>
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
        var displayScore = "your score";
        myWindow.document.write("<p> + displayScore + </p>")
        myWindow.focus();
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

it is the best way to directly open the new window with score.

if you have a result.html page then you can pass the score by query string or you can write the javascript code in the result.html page to access any of the cookies, localStorage or sessionStorage to get the score. but make sure you have saved your score in any of it.

Comment: are you looking for the same thing above?